# Beta Sites Close Reason is Incorrect

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-reasons, beta-phase

In the close reasons on the new Gadgets beta, you can see an in correct close reason.

[Oops http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/7806/incorrectsite.png](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/7806/incorrectsite.png)
*Click for larger image*

Comment: ha, that happens to all new betas :)

Comment: @Juan, has this been brought up here on meta yet?

Comment: It was brought up in the site specific meta... that now that I think about it, this post should be there, as it's specific to that SE

Comment: @Juan, no, it should be here because it happens in all SE sites.

Comment: @Juan...WAH!?! - Look at your first comment.  I'm confused.  You sad it was a bug on all new betas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the future open this on the per-site meta, as this is an issue **SPECIFIC TO THAT WEBSITE**.